# Can I save my place in an info file?

Tags: info, persistence, saveplace

I am reading through [An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/eintr.html) in an emacs buffer. I get to the file through `C-h i` and navigated to `Emacs Lisp Intro`. If I kill the buffer and return the same way, it takes me back to the table of contents. I have save-place enabled in my init file with the following code.

```
(setq-default save-place t)
```

How can I save my place in an info file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set a bookmark to where you are. Normally it is bound to <kbd>C-x r m</kbd>, and you can give it a name.

To see the list of bookmarks, <kbd>C-x r l</kbd>.